# Legend based on the color of nodes of a NetworkX graph

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, networkx

I'm trying to make a network graph with NetworkX and am stuck with two problems. I can't get the background color to be transparent or white, and I'm stuck with a light grey background. When I try to save this graph as a `png` it gives me an empty image.

Also, I'm trying to add a legend to the graph based on the colors of the nodes, but I am not sure what I'm doing wrong there.

Can someone help with a fix for this?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(24,18))
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'white'   # DOESN'T WORK

G = nx.Graph()
pos = nx.random_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, alpha=0.5, linewidths=3, node_color=[x[1]['color'] for x in G.nodes(data=True)], node_size=[150*x[1]['size'] for x in G.nodes(data=True)])
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=10, font_color='#1b1b1b', font_weight='bold', font_family='sans-serif')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color='grey', width=[0.4*x[2]['width'] for x in G.edges(data=True)])
plt.legend(dict_colors.values(), dict_colors.keys())  # DOESN'T WORK
plt.savefig("Network.png", transparent=True)  # DOESN'T WORK
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your graph is empty in your example. So there's nothing to draw. Do you define your graph elsewhere? Not sure why you are getting a gray background though.

Comment: Yeah, I have defined the nodes and edges elsewhere with a series of loops. The graph is showing up fine, so I didn't include that code.

Comment: It'd be helpful to provide a small example. Just some thoughts, you might be setting your nodes too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the legend with -

```
import Color from colour

plt.legend(handles=[Patch(facecolor=Color(val).hex, label=key) for key, val in dict_colors.items()])
```